# Matching a word in comma separated list in bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to find an exact match in a bash script, in a comma separated list of words.

I have tried using grep with various flags, like grep -w but it does not work.

I have this:

```
haystack="foo 1,bar"
needle="foo"
if [[ $( echo $haystack | grep $needle ) ]]; then
    echo exists
else
    echo does not exist
fi
```

With the example above, "foo 1" must NOT match. What happens now, is it finds a match, but i don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Bash regex matching with `(,|^)foo(,|$)` pattern:

```
haystack="foo 1,bar"
needle='(,|^)foo(,|$)'
if [[ "$haystack" =~ $needle ]]; then
    echo 'exists'
else
    echo 'does not exist'
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/x0KVdE)

The regex matches

- `(,|^)` - either `,` or start of a string
- `foo` - some `foo` char sequence
- `(,|$)` - `,` or end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop in an awk script to iterate over comma separated fields and check if any of them is `foo`.

```
haystack='foo 1,bar'
needle='foo'
echo "$haystack" | awk -F',' -v needle="$needle" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i==needle){print "exists";exit 0}}} END{print "doesn\047t exist";exit 1}'
```

This way you won't need to escape regex-active characters in your *needle*.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace comma with newline and then use `grep -x` (exact match):

```
haystack="foo 1,bar"

needle="foo"
grep -qFx "$needle" <<< "${haystack//,/$'\n'}" && echo "exists" || echo "does not exist"
does not exist

needle="foo 1"
grep -qFx "$needle" <<< "${haystack//,/$'\n'}" && echo "exists" || echo "does not exist"
exists
```